# How to monitor a process for crashes and collect core dumps

Tags: java, linux, macos, unix, coredump

I have a java program that launches other programs, and manages stopping them, etc.

I'd like to collect core dumps if any of the subprocesses crash. This is problematic in some cases when relying on the 'normal' way of getting core dumps:

- on linux, the core pattern can be arbitrarily complex, and sometimes doesn't even create a file. (and this is a global setting)
- on osx, core dumps are not created by default, and changing this requires admin rights.

Essentially, I'm looking for something similar to windows' [ProcDump](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/dd996900.aspx)

The platforms I'm interested in are:

- Linux
- OSX
- Solaris
- HP-UX
- AIX

Linux & OSX are the ones which are causing me trouble right now, but it would be nice if there was something I could use across all of them.

I can't modify the subprocesses I'm launching, but I could probably wrap them with some shell script or something.